# Problem compiling exiv2 code in VS 2022: Undefined Reference/symbol error

Tags: visual-c++, undefined-reference, undefined-symbol, exiv2

I have some code in Linux that uses exiv2 to read the metadata of a folder full of photos, depending on requirements it can reconstruct missing metadata, and stamp a logo as well as lat/long onto the photos. I'm trying to port it into windows visual studio so that I can make a GUI and let other people use it.

I downloaded the MSVS source code for exiv2, I've added the include folder and lib folders both in the include line and the linker line in the project properties dialogue. When I try to compile I get an undefined reference error whenever an EXIV2 object is called.

I'm guessing I have some sort of linking or library building issue. I built it on linux using g++ and had no problems. If I weren't trying to make a GUI I'd probably just get a windows version of g++ to compile with.

This is one of the error messages I'm getting.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::_List_iterator<class std::_List_val<struct std::_List_simple_types > > __thiscall Exiv2::ExifData::begin(void)" (_*imp*?begin@ExifData@Exiv2@@QAE?AV?$_List_iterator@V?$_List_val@U?$_List_simple_types@VExifdatum@Exiv2@@@std@@@std@@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "int __cdecl uptake(class std::vector<struct EANphoto,class std::allocator > &,char *,char *)" (?uptake@@YAHAAV?$vector@UEANphoto@@V?$allocator@UEANphoto@@@std@@@std@@PAD1@Z) CAPconsole  C:\Users\ [redacted] \source\repos\CAPconsole\CAPconsole.obj    1

I've tried adding include files for both the "include" and the "lib" folders to both the include line and to the linker. I also tried to compile the sample program that came with Exiv2, and I get the same error,so I'm guessing it's a VS setting issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, the way to do this is as follow:

In "Properties" … "C/C++" … "General" … "Additional Include Directories", add the include and lib folders, and do the same in
"Linker" … "Additional Library Directories".

Finally, in "Linker" … "Command Line" … "Additional Options", write in "exiv2.lib".